# regular expression find the last character of repeating characters

Tags: regex, perl

I've searched Stack Overflow for similar questions but could not find one. What I'd like to have is a regular expression (I'm using Perl) to find the last occurrence of a **possible** repeating characters.

For example, `a;b;c;;;d,;ee`, I want to call the `split` function to split on very last of `;` in this string, so that the results after split would be `[a b c;; d, ee]`.

Thanks

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468999/how-can-i-split-a-perl-string-only-on-the-last-occurrence-of-the-separator) is similar but not what I want. For my example, I want a list of 5 items `[a b c;; d, ee]`. The other question would give out a list of two items `[a;b;c;; d,ee]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a Perl string only on the last occurrence of the separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468999/how-can-i-split-a-perl-string-only-on-the-last-occurrence-of-the-separator)

Comment: Thanks. Above one is close but not what I want. For my example, I want a list of 5 items  [a b c;; d, ee]. The other question would give out a list of two items [a;b;c;;  d,ee]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split /;(?!;)/
```

(Split only on `;` not followed by `;`)

Comment: I need to read this [article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which works by bypassing all but the last semicolon of a sequence

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @vals = split /;*\K;/, 'a;b;c;;;d,;ee';

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@vals;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c;;',
          'd,',
          'ee'
        ];
```

Answer (score -3):

Use capture groups.

```
my ( $first, $last ) = $string =~ /(.*);([^;]*)$/;
```